# How do $E_q[p(x|z)]$ becomes the cross entropy between $x$, and $p(x|z)$?

Tags: bayesian, autoencoders, kullback-leibler, cross-entropy

In variational autoencoders we get the difference between $q_\theta(z|x)$, and intractable $p_\phi(z|x)$ by calculating the ELBO with respect to their parameters by breaking it down to:

$$E_q[p_\phi(x|z)] - KL(q_\theta(z|x)||p(z))$$

And in practice we're calculating the binary cross entropy between $x$ (input fed into the encoder), and $p_\phi(x|z)$ (output of the decoder derived from $z$).

What is the breakdown of this?